# Property does not exist on type 'Component'

Tags: angular, angular7

I am new to angular and I want to delete a machine but I get an error in the console :

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "Bad Request", url: "http://localhost:3001/machines/delete", ok: false, …}
```

I don't know how to solve it. that's my component code:

```
constructor (MachinesService: MachinesService, private toastr: 
ToastrService) {
MachinesService.getMachines().subscribe(
    res => {
          console.log(res);
          this.machines = res;
    },

    err => {
          console.log(err);
    }
  );

    }

       delete(id) {
    this.MachinesService.deleteMachine(id).subscribe();
  }
```

and my machinesService.ts :

```
 deleteMachine(id): Observable<any> {
 return this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + '/machines/delete', id);
```

I have already worked with the same code and it worked well but I don't know what is the problem now.
NB : it work in the backend.

Comment: Did you try `constructor (` **`private`** `MachinesService: MachinesService, private toastr: ToastrService)` instead? And BTW, you should call the variable `machinesService`, not `MachinesService`.... just saying.

Comment: Opps i forgot it ;( thank you ....... noted : i will thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `private` before the constructor argument. That's what also makes it a property.

And please, don't name the variable the same way as the type. Use a lowercase first character for variables.